# É possível instalar um serviço do windows a partir de uma DLL? (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, windows, dll, services

Eu possuo uma dll que possui métodos que deverão ser executados num serviço do windows. Eu fiz uma pesquisa e vi que para instalar um serviço, eu precisaria de um executável. Possuo a versão 2007 do Delphi e Windows 7. Algo como:

```
rundll32.exe <nomedll>.dll /install
```